# Having two way view in notepad++ of different logs

Tags: notepad++

I am working on a application of which different logs are created and and these logs are getting updates parallely now I want open two logs sententiously that I can do in notepad++ in different tab individually, but I was looking for two way mirror approach that is one view two logs get opened simultaneously , one log is at left and the other log is opened at right so that every time I don't need to switch in tabs..!! Please advise how to achieve this in notepad++..!!

Answer (score 1):

You can just right click on a tab and choose "move to other view" to get side by side documents open in Notepad++.